# Curl build from source on AIX facing issue

Tags: curl, makefile, openssl, libcurl, aix

I am facing below error while trying to build libcurl curl-7.61.0 on AIX platform.

```
uname -a
AIX test-aix6 1 6 00C95C354C00
```

I have first built openssl openssl-1.1.0h using below steps

```
./config --prefix=/home/openssl/openssl-1.1.0h
make 
make install
```

This builts OK
Then i attempted to built libcurl as below

```
./configure --prefix=/home/curl-7.61.0 --with-ssl=/home/openssl/openssl-1.1.0h/
```

But when i issue below command from /home/curl-7.61.0 directory

```
make -bnoquiet
```

then i am getting below errors

```
xlC_r -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src   -qthreaded -qnoansialias -qhalt=e -O2 -I/home/openssl/openssl-1.1.0h//include -I/home/openssl/openssl-1.1.0h//include/openssl   -c -o ../lib/curl-curl_ctype.o `test -f '../lib/curl_ctype.c' || echo './'`../lib/curl_ctype.c
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `../lib/libcurl.la', needed by `curl'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/curl-7.61.0/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/curl-7.61.0/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I have even tried to add openssl lib directory in LD_LIBRARY_PATH as well as in LIBPATH but still no success.

Any pointers where i am going wrong?

Comment: There might be other error messages before that. Try `make -C lib libcurl.la`

Comment: If i issue this command then it builds libcurl.la OK But then again if i issue make command i run into same error as reported above.

Comment: It usually helps to narrow it down if you invoke `make V=1` and inspect the full command line. Something is weirdly wrong there for you...

Comment: There must other messages you failed to quote: a simple compiling doesn't require any .la files

Comment: echo "  CC      " ../lib/curl-curl_ctype.o;source='../lib/curl_ctype.c' object='../lib/curl-curl_ctype.o' libtool=no \
DEPDIR=.deps depmode=xlc /bin/sh ../depcomp \
cc -qlanglvl=extc89 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src   -qthreaded -qnoansialias -qhalt=e -O2  -pthread   -c -o ../lib/curl-curl_ctype.o `test -f '../lib/curl_ctype.c' || echo './'`../lib/curl_ctype.c
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `../lib/libcurl.la', needed by `curl'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/curl-7.61.0/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

Comment: @Lorinczy Zsigmond - I scanned thru whole compile log and thats the only error message occurrence (as above).
1 more observation - find for libcurl.la in curl directory doesnt locate any such file. However issuing make -C lib libcurl.la goes fine to success

Comment: Then just edit your original question and quote the complete output of these commands: 1. `make -C lib V=1 libcurl.la` 2. `make -C src V=1 curl`

Comment: make -C lib V=1 libcurl.la results in below messages now
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .EVP_MD_CTX_new
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .EVP_MD_CTX_free
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .OpenSSL_version_num
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .X509_get0_notBefore
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .X509_get0_notAfter
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .X509_get_X509_PUBKEY
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .OPENSSL_sk_num
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .OPENSSL_sk_value
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .X509_get_version

Comment: undef symbols list ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .EVP_MD_CTX_new
.EVP_MD_CTX_free
.OpenSSL_version_num
.X509_get0_notBefore
.X509_get0_notAfter
.X509_get_X509_PUBKEY
.OPENSSL_sk_num
.OPENSSL_sk_value
.X509_get_version
.X509_get0_extensions
.EVP_PKEY_id
.EVP_PKEY_get0_DSA
.DSA_get0_pqg
.DSA_get0_key
.EVP_PKEY_get0_DH
.DH_get0_pqg
.DH_get0_key
.EVP_PKEY_get0_RSA
.RSA_get0_key
.X509_get0_signature
.SSL_get0_alpn_selected
.TLS_client_method
.SSL_CTX_set_options
.SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos
.SSL_CTX_set_next_proto_select_cb
.ASN1_STRING_get0_data
.OPENSSL_sk_pop_free

Comment: @Lorinczy Zsigmond - I have attached the undefined symbol list in my previous above 2 comments which are seen upon using command make -C lib V=1 libcurl.la

Comment: Now please edit your original question and quote the complete output [or at least the _first_ 20 lines] of this command: `make -C lib V=1 libcurl.la`

Answer (score 0):

You need curl linked with exact SSL version? If you just need some curl i would not recommend to build it on your own. Build something on AIX is always painful. You can easily install curl with RPM from [www.perzl.org](http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=Main.HomePage) (don't forget to install all dependencies)